# python: extracting specific lines from all files in a zip archive

Tags: python, zip

I need to extract a specific line (the second line) from all the files contained in a zip archive. My attempts (obviously) didn't work. Everything I could find related to this involved using a specific string/variable to narrow down the contents to be extracted from archived files - I can't use that in my case.

The closest I've gotten is extracting ALL lines from ALL files.

```
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile() as input_zipfile:
    for f in input_zipfile.namelist():
         for line in input_zipfile.read(f).split("\n"):
               print line
```

Ideally I would want to use something like `.readlines()` and then `print line[1]` to get the second line of each file. But that doesn't work with zipfiles. Do I need to create temporary files and use that syntax, or is there a way around this?

I tried changing the last line to `print line[1]` but then I get an `IndexError`.

As a side note, the files aren't large (4-12 lines). So I guess making temporary files isn't out of the question, but it seems too roundabout and inelegant.

Comment: did you try just changing your last line to print line[1] ? (and you're missing a colon at the end of the for loop line, but I assume that was just an editing error when you prepared this on stackoverflow)

Comment: thanks for pointing out the typo.

I get an "IndexError: string index out of range" when trying line[1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile() as input_zipfile:
    for f in input_zipfile.namelist():
        lines = input_zipfile.read(f).split("\n")
        print lines[1]
```

(Your original code loops through the list of lines for no reason, instead of just printing the 2nd)